# PHPExcel Mulitple excel file in one HTML page

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have 2 xls, i want to plot this information into one HTML Page.

Note: For assumption i mentioned as xls. actual xls positions are already in the database table. i will just render these position and plot into HTML Page.

```
include_once("Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php");
// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

//first excel file


$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
           ->setCellValue('c5','10');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
           ->setCellValue('c6','20');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
           ->setCellValue('c7','30');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
           ->setCellValue('c8','40');


$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'HTML');

//second excel file

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
           ->setCellValue('c5','50');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
           ->setCellValue('c6','60');


$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'HTML');        

$objWriter->save('combinedexcelpage.html');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to go through a long explanation of why this doesn't work, because it would take too long to explain; but there are a couple of solutions that you could take to achieve what you want:

**Option #1**

An Excel workbook comprises one or more worksheets, so you could create each "file" as a separate worksheet, rather than a separate file.

```
//  Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

//  First excel worksheet, (created when you instantiate a new PHPExcel object)
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('c5','10');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('c6','20');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('c7','30');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('c8','40');

//  Second excel worksheet
//  Add new sheet, which should also set it as the new "active" sheet
$objPHPExcel->createSheet()

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('c5','50');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('c6','60');
```

By default, the HTML Writer will only write a single worksheet (the first), but you can set it to write all sheets:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'HTML'); 
$objWriter->writeAllSheets();
$objWriter->save('combinedexcelpage.html');
```

**Option #2**

The HTML Writer save() method will always generate a file stream (whether a filesystem file or php://output), but rather than using save(), you can call individual methods in the class to generate a string containing the formatted worksheet data, and build your own output from those "blocks".

```
$data = '';

//  First excel file
$objPHPExcel1 = new PHPExcel();

$objPHPExcel1->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('c5','10');
$objPHPExcel1->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('c6','20');
$objPHPExcel1->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('c7','30');
$objPHPExcel1->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('c8','40');

$objWriter1 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'HTML');
$objWriter1->generateStyles(false);
$data .= $objWriter1->generateHTMLHeader();
$data .= $objWriter1->generateSheetData();

//  Second excel file
$objPHPExcel2 = new PHPExcel();

$objPHPExcel2->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('c5','50');
$objPHPExcel2->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('c6','60');

$objWriter2 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel2, 'HTML');        
$objWriter2->generateStyles(false);
$data .= $objWriter2->generateSheetData();
$data .= $objWriter2->generateHTMLFooter();

file_put_contents('combinedexcelpage.html', $data);
```

Both of these options are described in section 6.8 of the developer documentation